# How to detect USB mixer(audio) device but not mouse, Keyboard, or other USB devices in C++ code?

Tags: c++, windows, libusb, usb-drive

Currently, I am using a recording application which gets input from USB mixer device. I wrote a code that whenever the device is disconnected, the recording should be stopped and when it reconnects, it restarts the audio service and continues the recording.

But the problem is, it is stopping the recording if mouse, keyboard wire or even a pendrive is disconnected. The Guid I used in the code is below:

```
static const GUID GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USBSTOR = { 0xA5DCBF10L,
                                               0x6530,
                                               0x11D2,
                                               {0x90, 0x1F, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x4F, 0xB9, 0x51, 0xED} };
```

Can someone tell me how to detect only the device which has audio input and exclude USBs like pendrive, mouse etc.?

Each customer might use different audio input device - which has 8 channels if it helps. So I can't hard code any specifications.

I am using Presonus USB mixer.

Comment: SetupAPI or similar when you get the device message?

Comment: Its not SetupAPI. I am using OnDeviceChange in CPP using WM_DEVICECHANGE message. I am registering device notification using the above mentioned GUID.